# Becoming captain in player career mode

Tags: fifa-15

I still can't figure out how to be the captain in player career mode.
I've played as ST, CAM, and CDM. I'm always the best player in the team- I have the highest rating, I score the most goals and I have the most assists in the league. I've stayed with this team for 7 seasons but never got picked as captain.

Is there something I'm missing? Is there a trick to being made captain?

Answer (score 1):

According to EA Sports, you may have to re-install the game to fix the bug. They are also looking to release a patch to see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score -3):

You have to play 13 seasons at one team, and after this you can be a captain.

Comment: Do you have a source for this?